SIM800L is unresponsive to AT commands
SIMM800L connected to Arduino UNO doesn't respond to AT command.
The serial monitor stops at
"initializing..."
the LED blinks every 3 seconds
VDD --> connected to 5v of the Arduino uno
    #include <SoftwareSerial.h>

//Create software serial object to communicate with SIM800L
SoftwareSerial mySerial(3, 2); //SIM800L Tx & Rx is connected to Arduino #3 & #2

void setup()
{
  //Begin serial communication with Arduino and Arduino IDE (Serial Monitor)
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  //Begin serial communication with Arduino and SIM800L
  mySerial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("Initializing...");
  delay(1000);

  mySerial.println("AT"); //Once the handshake test is successful, it will back to OK
  updateSerial();
  mySerial.println("AT+CSQ"); //Signal quality test, value range is 0-31 , 31 is the best
  updateSerial();
  mySerial.println("AT+CCID"); //Read SIM information to confirm whether the SIM is plugged
  updateSerial();
  mySerial.println("AT+CREG?"); //Check whether it has registered in the network
  updateSerial();
}

void loop()
{
  updateSerial();
}

void updateSerial()
{
  delay(500);
  while (Serial.available()) 
  {
    mySerial.write(Serial.read());//Forward what Serial received to Software Serial Port
  }
  while(mySerial.available()) 
  {
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());//Forward what Software Serial received to Serial Port
  }
}


VDD --> connected to 5v of the Arduino uno ... you have to connect the GND and data lines also

Please use a separate power supply for the GSM module. Powering from Arduino board's VCC pin is not going to work.

I have worked a lot with SIM800L recently and usually people do the same mistakes working with it:

SIM800L expects to be supplied with 4V, not 5V.
It requires up to 2A of current, which can't be provided by Arduino powered from USB.
Arduino works with 5V logic level, but SIM800L with 3.3V. So you need to use a level converter or at least to connect RX pin of SIM800L through a resistive divider - two resistors 5K and 10K.
GND pin of Arduino must be connected to GND pin of SIM800L.

Each of these points can be the reason why your SIM800L isn't responding. Please make sure that all these requirements are satisfied, otherwise you can even burn your GSM module.

Thank you for your generous advice. I will try.
